# Being redirected to 127.0.0.1 from IPv4 Address

Tags: apache, magento, localhost, redirect

I am developing a website locally and I want to view the content on my phone in order to test the site's responsive design. I can access  the website at `127.0.0.1/magento` from my desktop browser. After trying (and failing) to use Google Chrome's remote debugging and Adobe Edge Inspect CC, I realized that I can access my Apache server over the network (Pardon my poor terminology, I don't know very much about networking).

Basically, I can type in my computer's IPv4 address (`10.1.100.126`) into my the URL bar on my phone and I get my WampServer default page (the same page I'd get if I went to `localhost` in my desktop browser). I can access two of my other [defunct] projects by going to the expected URLs, such as `10.1.100.126/` followed by the name of the project as listed on my `localhost` page. These two webpages that I *can* access are not made in any content management system, but rather, they're constructed from plain HTML and CSS.

**Here is my issue:** when I try to access my main project (developed in Magento, sadly) by going to `10.1.100.126/magento`, I am redirected to `127.0.0.1/magento`. Obviously, that fails, because the server isn't on my phone. What are some reasons I might be getting redirected to `127.0.0.1` from `10.1.100.126'? I realize there are a lot of things that could be leading to this, but can anyone help me out?

[Possibly] Relevant info about my setup:

- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- developing on Magento Community Edition 1.9.0.1
- using WampServer 2.5 (bundled: Apache 2.4.9, MySQL 5.6.17, PHP 5.5.12)
- using Chrome 41.0.2267.0 Canary (64-bit) on my desktop
- my phone is a Samsung Galaxy S4 (AT&T version, SGH-I337) on Android 4.4.2, using Chrome Beta 40.0.2214.45
- if I go to `localhost/warrior` on my desktop, I get redirected to `127.0.0.1/magento`. This does not happen with my other websites, such as `/warrior-old`, which works as expected when prefixed with either `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. This seems to imply that my Magento website `/magento` has some setting affecting it directly.

Please let me know if providing an Apache log or configuration file would help (I didn't post them originally because they're very long and I'm not sure if they contain sensitive information about my computer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento saves the address of your application on the DB and uses it to create all urls. Here's what you have to do:

Open a mysql console and type:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_%';
```

You will see you have 127.0.0.1/magento on there. You have two options

1. You can change it manually through mysql/phpMyAdmin by doing a simple

   ```
   update core_config_data set value = 'http://10.1.100.126/magento/' where path like '%base_url'
   ```

   or,
2. Go to the magento config, System->Configuration->Web->Unsecure and Secure and input the values appropriately, on Base Url, enter

   ```
   http://10.1.100.126/magento/
   ```

Delete the cache and the sessions (I've seen them cause problems) and you should be good to go.

You can also configure magento to use two different urls, see:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup

Comment: You want to use your outside IP address `10.1.100.126` for your Magento `base_url`.  Then in your local hosts file under `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` **on the computer where Magento is installed**, you want to add `10.1.100.126   localhost` so the computer knows to load `localhost` for that IP instead of causing a redirect loop.

Comment: I changed the base URL to `10.1.100.126/magento/` and things work correctly now, from both my phone and computer. Now... isn't that IP address local and subject to change? I don't know anything about subnets and stuff, but I feel like 10.1.126.126 isn't a permanent IP address. Is there any way to do this with more stability/permanence? Or will that always work as long as I am on the same network?

Comment: The `10.1.100.126` IP address is a **local network IP address** assigned to your computer from your internet router.  You will want to login to your router configuration and assign a static/fixed IP address to your computer to ensure it never changes.  This IP cannot be accessed externally outside of your network (via the internet) as it's a **local IP address unique to your local network**.

Comment: @Axel, about your first comment, did you mean "You want to use your _local_ IP address `10.1.100.126`"? Wouldn't the _outside_ address be the router's IP, 72.78.xx.xx? I'm asking so I can learn a little about networking terminology, it's all a little confusing. Thanks a bunch for the info otherwise! **Edit:** does "outside IP address" = "external IP address" = "public IP address"?

Comment: Yes, correct.  I meant "outside" not as in "internet", but "outside" your computer.  Poor word choice.  It's actually your internal network IP (not accessible from the internet).  The outside address is indeed your external IP address seen from the internet's perspective.  Most likely your router and or ISP do not allow incoming web traffic on port 80 (if you attempt to access your outside IP address from the internet, it will most likely not connect).  Setting that up requires some further configuration.